# Do users of One for All lose their original quirks?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Izuku and All Might didn't have quirks when receiving One for All, but at least some of the former users had an original quirk.

Did these users lose their quirks along with One for All when they pass One for All to another user?

Comment: It's yet to be revealed to us. The specifics of Nana's death will be closely tied with Shigaraki's developments, while we know even less about the holders before her.

Answer (score 1):

All of the previous owners of One For All have passed their quirks on to the power and its successors which would be highly indicative that the user of One For All retains their original quirk when receiving the power

[One For All](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/One_For_All)

> Over time, One For All has amassed the Quirks of all the users. Now, Izuku is starting to manifest some of those Quirks. This first showed itself during the Joint Training Battle with Class 1-B. He starts with Blackwhip, a Quirk that reacted to Izuku's anger and wanting to capture Neito Monoma. Izuku has five other Quirks to discover and become able to use.

> One of the previous holders of One For All explained that seeing the traces is a side effect of the core of One For All itself growing. The original Quirk factors that had belonged to previous bearers of One For All had merged with the core of One For All. This previous holder of One For All explained that the core of One For All was concealed by the trait of One For All that stockpiles power and that the core of One For All is growing.

Comment: His question isn't whether they retain the power when _receiving_ OFA. It's more about how the passing on of their non-OFA quirk works. Would it be inevitable, making the predecessor quirkless after the transfer, or is it a voluntary merger of OFA and their quirks. Given the nature of OFA, I'd guess it's the latter. Anyway, I realize we don't have much info on this yet, considering how Izuku is the first person to even see those past images much less their quirks. Good attempt though.

Comment: Also, you might want to mark the part about Izuku's new power up in a spoiler tag, since this is a major development in the manga but yet to appear in the anime

Comment: @TheGamer007 I tried to add spoiler blocks but it does not appear to be working.

Comment: I've made an edit to fix it. I guess the spoiler tags don't work as expected when there's only whitespace in between them, unlike with normal quote tags.

Comment: @TheGamer007 Thanks, and the edit has been approved.